# Reopening Closed threads

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I do not know what I should do open my question again.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392096/upcoming-computer-books

Could you reopen my thread again? My question was about software engineering :( And I could not find a topic in which what we should do for a closed topic.

And please add an action like talking moderators or something else to express our excuse.

Thanks

Comment: To reopen the question, five site members would have to vote to reopen it.  Your original question does not meet the criteria for Stack Overflow questions, so I don't think you will find people wanting to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

I was one of the people who voted to close your question, because I don't think it's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Besides the question being poorly worded and the body of the question not matching the title, it is not programming related.

One of the methods I use to determine if a question is "programming related" is to replace the word "programming" with "knitting". If the question still makes sense, then it is not programming-related.  For example:

> Is there a web site to figure out what are the upcoming [programming] books?

becomes:

> Is there a web site to figure out what are the upcoming [knitting] books?

Yup, that question still makes sense. So therefore I conclude that the question is about books, not about programming, and should be closed.

(Suggestion: If you're interested in finding out what books are about to be published, try looking on the publisher's website, or subscribe to a magazine about books.)

PS: re "And please add an action like talking moderators or something else to express our excuse." -- there already is such an "action". Click the "flag" link to get a moderator's attention, and express your "excuse" in the text box that pops up.

Comment: But: Which 'the publisher'?

Comment: @D_N: O'Reilly and Sams are two big publishers of computer books. I have found that large bookstores will also give you updates about books coming in on various subjects. My point is that none of this has to do specifically with programming.

Answer (score 2):

There is a distinction between programming as an activity (which primarily involves working with source code of some kind, databases, source control systems, unit testing frameworks, etc) and programming as a profession (which also involves a lot of things like reading books or other training materials, career paths, conferences, professional etiquette, etc that only peripherally support programming the activity).  Please don't confuse the two.  StackOverflow is meant mainly to cover just the former.

That said, StackOverflow is also structured in such a way as to allow a certain amount of the latter type of question.  But whether your programming-profession-related question will pass or not is akin to winning the lottery.  You'll get no further whining if it's closed and forgotten than you would if your weekly Pick 5 comes up empty.  Hopefully, most programmers are smart enough to know better than to play the lottery.

Personally, I would be unlikely to vote to close your question.  Like Ether I have a test I normally apply; I think about how I would tag the question if I were posting it to a general purpose site.  Would I tag it `programming`, or would I tag it something else, like `career-development` or `training`?  In this case, I would likely tag it `training`, `books`, and `programming`, and so it passes my litmus test.  But I also don't generally vote to re-open questions that are borderline.  The reason it's borderline is because I can't also narrow it down to a specific *kind* of programming: say `java`, `.net`, `javascript`, `database`, `php`, etc.